# Different charts in same <div> with d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

In my first works with library [d3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3) I found one problem that I don't know how to solve.
I am trying to represent data I receive from one web service in same `<div>`.
It works like that:

1. User selects one date in drop-down menu.
2. User clicks button.
3. Request to server.
4. (If everything went fine) Response with JSON data.
5. Represent data in chart

This can be repeated many times in same page and chart should be updated.

I am trying to represent those charts in same div.
Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div id="featured-results">
User message I want to remove
</div>
<div id="featured-content">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){                                
    var ip = location.host;
    var data = [];
    var req = $.ajax({
        url: 'http://...' ,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        cache: 'true',
        success: function(response){
            data = response;
        }
    });
    $.when(req).done(function(){
        var barWidth = 9;
        var width = 950;
        var height = 350;

        var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 96]).range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 1000]).rangeRound([1, height - 50]);

        d3.select("#featured-results").remove();                           

        var chart = d3.select("#featured-content")
            .append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

        chart.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data.values)
            .enter()
            .append("svg:rect")
            .attr("x", function(datum, index){return x(index);})
            .attr("y", function(datum){return height - y(datum.energy);})
            .attr("height", function(datum){return y(datum.energy);})
            .attr("width", barWidth)
            .attr("fill", "#2d578b");                                        
     });
}
</script>
```

This code removes one div where I show a message for the user and represents the chart in  `<div id="featured-content">` div but when I request for a new chart the new chart is appended to the div and then I see two, three, ...

How can I do that? It is any 'best-practice' for that?
Thanks

**Update:** If I remove all svg's does not represents the current chart

```
d3.select("#featured-results").remove();

d3.selectAll("svg:svg").remove();
var chart = d3.select("#featured-content") 
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

chart.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data.values)
    .enter()
    .append("svg:rect")
    .attr("x", function(datum, index){return x(index);})
    .attr("y", function(datum){return height - y(datum.energy);})
    .attr("height", function(datum){return y(datum.energy);})
    .attr("width", barWidth)
    .attr("fill", "#2d578b");
```

Comment: You can remove all existing `svg` elements before you add a new one.

Comment: Yes, but how? Like that: `d3.selectAll("svg:svg").remove();`?

Comment: Yep. Or just `d3.select("svg:svg").remove();`, since there should only be one at a time, right?

Comment: But is not working to me. It does not loads the `svg` I want to represent.

Comment: You mean it does not show the new data? You have to remove the `svg` element before you add the new one.

Comment: Now is working following @Aaron's advice. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal approach is to toggle visibility of the two `div`s with `show()` and `hide()`.

Loading new content with d3.js will append to any existing content. If you don't want that, use `d3.select("#featured-content").html('');`.

Comment: But is appending charts in same div... Is not replacing one for another.

Comment: ah. Call `.empty()` on the second `div` before calling d3.js

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed you're not using jQuery. Try `div.html('');` instead